# How to disable browser backbutton after signout from website in java

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, struts

How to **disable the browser backbutton** after **signout / logout** for my website. I am using jsp and struts1, i am using this code but this is not working properly (i.e in all pages the browser backbutton is not working but my requirement is was not that one) .

```
    <script>
        history.forward();
    </script>
```

Please any one help me.

Comment: @TJ its using javascript, but i want to do it in java, so why it is duplicat of that one

Comment: java runs on a server. back button is on your client. (browser). if there's no option for closing called *this doesn't make sence* . Also, if you don't want to do it using javascript, then why did you **tag** javascript..?

Comment: @TJ, ok,i agreed your point, i am new for stackoverflow .., Thanks for your valuable reply

Comment: You need to set no-cache headers so the page will not be cached. If its cached then it might be available still.

Comment: try some spring- security type framework. it is useful in security wrapping application resources.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to disable the browser **back** button. You need to expire/invalidate the session when the user clicks **logout**. Then even if he clicks the **back** button, your app should detect that this request now comes with an invalid session, and so it would forward him to the **login** page (as he has no valid session already).

Comment: I cleared the session after logout, but cutomer clicks back ,the old page was available. How to resolve it.

Comment: You need to check session before loading each page. Are doing that ?

Comment: I am checking at all .classes but not in jsp

Comment: @user2767299 How to check ?